# deleting the row of cart when click on remove ImageVIewof row item in List

Tags: android, listview

I have shopping cart page but problem is that I can't remove the item from cart when click on remove Image ,In my database I have delete method,and in adapter of ListView I am giving OnClickListener on remove image,please have a look at my code and suggest me..
DataBasehelper1.java:

```
public int deleteContact(int id) {
       SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
       return db.delete(CONTACTS_TABLE_NAME, CONTACTS_PRODUCT_ID + " = "+id, null);
}
```

ListViewAdapter.java:

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

String productId = "0";
  public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

       holder.remove =(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.removeIV);

       holder.remove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
       db.deleteContact(Integer.valueOf(productId));
            //list.remove(getItem(position));

            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "removed ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: so you I guess you have called a function to delete but you are not updating the UI by removing the view

Comment: also you are deleting a productId which has value zero so always that particular row in your database will be deleted

Answer (score 0):

You should try this : db.deleteContact(Integer.valueOf(position));
The way you do it, it will always delete the first item in your database because you set productId=0 at the beginning.
And make sure to notify your adapter after deleting something from the database.

Comment: I have 10 products in my static app,and i have given product Id to each products in one fragment , can you please tell me the correct way to pass products id from that fragment to this adapter ?

Comment: can you please post the code from the fragment and the adapter? just update your original post